# mp3 file name replace

Tags: python, directory, rename, subdirectory

So my concern on a logic of a program.
I have a Music folder with many mp3 files with underscores in names (MC_-_Best_track.mp3). So I want to scan this folder and replace all underscores with whitespaces.

I want to write it myself first but I need a kickstart for that) Can you help me in logic?

Update:

Still struggle with subfolders.

{

```
import os 
path = r"C:\Users\mugger\Desktop\Music fo Python"

for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for subfolders in folders:
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), 
                os.path.join(path, file.replace("_"," ")))
```

}

If I set path directly I get only one file renamed and getting error:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\mugger\Desktop\programming\Udemy\0149. List of Possible Widgets.ipynb Cell 2 in <cell line: 6>()
8 for file in files:
9     if file.endswith(".mp3"):
---> 10         os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("_"," ")))

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\mugger\Desktop\Music fo Python\old\Queen - Under_Pressure.mp3' -> 'C:\Users\mugger\Desktop\Music fo Python\old\Queen - Under Pressure.mp3'

Comment: [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)/[os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and filter by format. Use regex for complex patterns or maybe just `srt.replace("_", " ")`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this maybe work

```
import os 

path = "your folder path"


data = os.listdir(path)


for  file in data:
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):


    file_name = file.lower()
    file = file_name
    

        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("_"," ")))
```

Comment: I think in this code we just want to rename the files in a folder not change the path or rename it if I miss something tell me please I edit my answer

Comment: You right check my edited answer please

Comment: You right thank you so much for your advice and information  I am also new to stack overflow why when my answer is correct nothing happen ? People must vote ?

Comment: Done this upper case letters was because of my phone keyboard

Comment: Yeah, no need to change path. Just replace underscores in filenames. Your code is working, now I'm trying to update it for my needs, Thanks)

Comment: @Ihor Koptilin yw if it's work for you I will very thankful if you approve my answer

Comment: I have one more question. Can this logic be used to change uppercase to lower? os.rename(os.path.join(root,name), os.path.join(root,name.replace("MP3","mp3"))) I've tried different options and nothing working. That's how far I gone): https://github.com/muggerseo/my_projects/edit/master/Name%20replace%20for%20music%20playlist.py

Those files, that cannot be renamed, goes to txt file. But when those files with uppercase were renamed they go to txt still despite they were renamed.

Comment: try this :   os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("_"," ").lower()))

Comment: I don't know why but renaming goes on first iteration and file extension change next iteration

Comment: I edit my answer check the answer I hope this solution work

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I want first letter of each track to be Uppercase. Still struggle but going step-by-step to finish)

Comment: so yopu can use .title() in this case i guess not .lower()